# automatically add "waiting approval" to a google sheets response page

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am currently working on a google form that'll be used to approve some requests.
I all I want to do is add "waiting approval" to column O on each response that comes through.

tried googling adding extra column into a response sheet.
Found nothing